# database fields from a store procedure in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a store procedure in SQL server 2005 as follow:

```
if @query = 1
select a, b
..... from table_a

if @query = 2
select
c, d, e, f
..... from table_b
```

In database expert menu ( or database location )

I put `@query = 2`, but there are only `a,b` are shown in database fields in crystal reports 2005 in visual studio 2005

Comment: crystal report expert menu only show your procedure's parameter not your select query columns inside your procedure. yes it column dispaly if you use tables rathar than parameter

Comment: Also you use same no of output in your procedure in different different condition  ,other wise you have to get this type of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comment first. Crystal report does not give multple dataset and with dynamic output based on your if else condition.

For this your final Select statement in your Stored Procedure as a output of procedure.

see this link to understand more.

https://forums.asp.net/t/1740901.aspx?Crystal+Reports+not+supporting+stored+procedure+with+multiple+SQL+Queries

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3556797

[Crystal Reports - Certain output from SQL not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638495/crystal-reports-certain-output-from-sql-not-displaying)

[Stored Procedure not showing fields in Crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325657/stored-procedure-not-showing-fields-in-crystal-reports)